# Should i produce new message or just consume old message in this case

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue

For order submision, we produce Kafka message A, the message includes all 30 fields for an order.

Now, we are going to create a new order real-time monitor system. We need only 8 fields of an order.

The question is coming.. should we produce new Kafka message B while order submission, or we dont need to and just need to add new consumer to subscribe the existing message A?

Which one is following the best practise and why

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it would be best to add a new consumer to subscribe to the existing message. There are a few advantages to this approach.

1. It's more efficient for the server registering the order since it is only sending one message instead of 2.
2. It's more efficient for your Kafka brokers. If you send two distinct messages that means the brokers have to store more data on their disks. This can be a significant overhead since kafka maintains multiple replicas of messages in order to handle broker failures without data loss, and keeps data on the brokers for a while until it expires. Also the more messages you send to Kafka, the more it stress's the broker's network, and cpu (especially if you are doing compression).
3. Reduces the chances for race conditions in the event of a failure. If you sent two distinct messages there are some error cases you would either have to handle or live with:

   - Consider the case where you send the complete order message first and then the summary order message. There is a corner case where the server could fail after it had sent the complete message, but before it sent the summary message. If this happens your monitoring system will lose data. Kafka does have some form of transactions which would probably solve this issue, but there is always a performance penalty for using transactions. Bbut if you just send one message you won't have this problem :) .

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @ilooner.  The primary advantage of Kafka as compared to traditional Queues is that same data can be consumed multiple times, with a different Consumer group.
Producing Order and Order Summary (subset of Order fields) would have
 1. Twice the Disk Space (times the Replication Factor)
 2. Twice the N/w usage

Go with a new Consumer Group.